# Reload module with Node.js require() from a watcher trigger

Tags: node.js, require, reload

I have an index.js that forms a web tier using app.listen() after defining some posts and gets. In it, I have watchr set to watch another .js file in a ./libs folder for any changes to it. Upon a change, I want it to propagate an update from a function it exports to index.js web services without rebooting them.

In index.js...

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var myObjFile = require('./libs/myObjFile.js');
var watchr = require('watchr');

var myWatchPath = process.cwd() + '\\libs\\myObjFile.js';
function myListener (changeTyle, fullPath, currentStat, previousStat) {
try {
   switch(changeType) {
      case 'update':
         delete require.cache[require.resolve('./libs/myObjFile.js');
         //for (const path in require.cache) {
         //   if (path.endsWith('myObjFile.js') {
         //      delete require.cache[require.resolve('./libs/myObjFile.js');
         //   }
         //}
         //myObjFile = {};
         myObjFile = require('./libs/myObjFile.js');
      }
   }
   catch (err) {
      console.log('err watcher: ' + err.message);
   }
function next (err) {
   return err.message;
}
var stalker = watchr.open(myWatchPath , myListener, next);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json( {
   extended: try
}));

app.get('/getStuff/', function (req, res) {
   var thisObj = new myObjFile.objCreate('my type', myUUID); 
   thisObj.consoleTest();
})
app.listen(1234);
```

You can see some of the stuff I have tried commented out in the middle of the watchr function.

```
//Now inside myObjFile.js
exports.objCreate = function (type, uuid) {
   ...
   function consoleTest() {
      console.log('test123');
   }
   ...
   return {
      ...
      consoleTest: consoleTest,
      ...
   };
```

What I expect to happen is that after I start the node.js index.js file with npm start, I can first call the web service get() and see 'test123' print to the console. Then I want to change 'test123' to 'testABC', and save the file, then when I call the get() again, I expect to see 'testABC' print to the console. For now, I continue to see 'test123' until I reboot the server, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Is there a way to reload a require() at run time?

Comment: Inside the file where the web service is located, is _that_ `myObj` being reassigned as well, or only in `index.js`? I'm guessing the answer is no based on your description.

Comment: Thx Patrick. I had a typo that led to confusion, my apologies. The web services are in the index.js for now. I updated the code above to reflect better what's happening in the get(). I use the file that's linked at the top of index.js (myObj). Then within each web service call I'm instantiating a unique object each time the web service gets called (thisObj). As you pointed out, I'm attempting to redefine the first var, myObj, by re-requiring it. My thought was this would automatically change the values for the second (thisObj) when the web service is called later, but it doesn't. Suggestions?

Comment: I've actually been working on an npm package for accomplishing exactly what you describe after reading your question. Would you accept an answer along the lines of _you can use this package to do it for you_, or are you looking specifically to find out why your approach doesn't work?

Comment: First, I'd like to understand why, and thank you! Unfortunately, this particular project is for a group that prevents bringing in npm packages that's not theirs, but for future purposes, I'd also like to check out your npm!

Comment: Alright, I'll write an answer to address both when I have time.

Comment: I've looked over your question a few times and there's some things that don't make sense. `myObj = require('./libs/myObjFile.js');` implies that `myObj.consoleTest()` should be the call in the web service. I don't see a definition for an `new objCreate()` constructor anywhere. Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Patrick, that's a valid critique. I was trying to keep it minimal, but left out that important detail that the console test was actually a nested function of the object itself and not at the root level of the .js. I changed the require (now myObjFile) to be clearer and showed a fuller definition of myObjCreate with the console test as a function exposed by the return within the export statement. Thanks for patience and helping with this.

Comment: Thanks again for updating your question. I'll look at it closely when I have more time.